# how to use css link in php code?

Tags: php, html, css, web

hi i'm doing my web programming h/w and got a problem

this is code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Music Viewer</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link href="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/09sp/labs/3-music/viewer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="header">

    <h1>190M Music Playlist Viewer</h1>
    <h2>Search Through Your Playlists and Music</h2>
    </div>

    <ul>

    <?php
    $songs = glob("songs/*.mp3");
    foreach ($songs as $songfile) {
    $text = file_get_contents($songfile);
    file_put_contents($songfile, strrev($text));
    basename($songfile)
    ?>
    <li><a href <?= "$songfile" ?>> <?= basename($songfile) ?></a> </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    $txt = glob("songs/*.txt"); 
    foreach ($txt as $textfile) {
    $textt = file_get_contents($textfile);
    file_put_contents($textfile, strrev($textt));
    basename($textfile)
    ?>
    <li><a href <?= "$textfile" ?>> <?= basename($textfile) ?></a> </li>
    <?php
    }
    ?>


    </ul>


    </body>
</html>
```

this is about showing the song lists in the folder using glob 
and i wanna apply same css style from html code which is

```
<link href="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/09sp/labs/3-music/viewer.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

how to do this ???

Comment: Which link and what kind of link you want to add??

Comment: You've got the link already in your `head` section. It applies to all elements in your `body` ... So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: my problem was css style was not applied to php code. i just added <div id~> to seperate php and solved it :o............. btw thanks for comments to help

Comment: css will only apply on html not on php code

Comment: i have checked your css is working, maybe u have few syntax error, parse error in your code

Comment: missing semi colon here: basename($songfile)

Comment: this will not work: <?= "$textfile" ?>